# search json array string with PHP keyword

Tags: php, json

i have URL JSON array www.example.com/json.php

```
[ {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, {"name":"ÅlandIslands","code": "AX"}, {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}, {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"}, {"name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"}, {"name": "Angola", "code": "AO"}, {"name": "Anguilla", "code": "AI"}, {"name": "Antarctica", "code": "AQ"}, {"name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "code": "AG"}, {"name": "Argentina", "code": "AR"}, {"name": "Armenia", "code": "AM"}, {"name": "Aruba", "code": "AW"}, {"name": "Australia", "code": "AU"}, {"name": "Austria", "code": "AT"}, {"name": "Azerbaijan", "code": "AZ"}, {"name": "Bahamas", "code": "BS"}, {"name": "Bahrain", "code": "BH"}, {"name": "Bangladesh", "code": "BD"}, {"name": "Barbados", "code": "BB"}, {"name": "Belarus", "code": "BY"}, {"name": "Belgium", "code": "BE"}, {"name": "Belize", "code": "BZ"}, {"name": "Benin", "code": "BJ"}, {"name": "Bermuda", "code": "BM"}, {"name": "Bhutan", "code": "BT"}, {"name": "Bolivia", "code": "BO"}, {"name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "code": "BA"}, {"name": "Botswana", "code": "BW"}, {"name": "Bouvet Island", "code": "BV"}, {"name": "Brazil", "code": "BR"}, {"name": "British Indian Ocean Territory", "code": "IO"}, {"name": "Brunei Darussalam", "code": "BN"}, {"name": "Bulgaria", "code": "BG"}, {"name": "Burkina Faso", "code": "BF"}, {"name": "Burundi", "code": "BI"}, {"name": "Cambodia", "code": "KH"}, {"name": "Cameroon", "code": "CM"}, {"name": "Canada", "code": "CA"}, {"name": "Cape Verde", "code": "CV"}, {"name": "Cayman Islands", "code": "KY"}, {"name": "Central African Republic", "code": "CF"}, {"name": "Chad", "code": "TD"}, {"name": "Chile", "code": "CL"},{"name": "China", "code": "CN"}, {"name": "Christmas Island", "code": "CX"}, {"name": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "code": "CC"}, {"name": "Colombia", "code": "CO"}, {"name": "Comoros", "code": "KM"}, {"name": "Congo", "code": "CG"}, {"name": "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the", "code": "CD"}, {"name": "Cook Islands", "code": "CK"}, {"name": "Costa Rica", "code": "CR"}, {"name": "Cote D\"Ivoire", "code": "CI"}, {"name": "Croatia", "code": "HR"}, {"name": "Cuba", "code": "CU"}, {"name": "Cyprus", "code": "CY"}, {"name": "Czech Republic", "code": "CZ"},{"name": "Denmark", "code": "DK"}, {"name": "Djibouti", "code": "DJ"}, {"name": "Dominica", "code": "DM"}, {"name": "Dominican Republic", "code": "DO"}, {"name": "Ecuador", "code": "EC"}, {"name": "Egypt", "code": "EG"}, {"name": "El Salvador", "code": "SV"}, {"name": "Equatorial Guinea", "code": "GQ"}, {"name": "Eritrea", "code": "ER"},
```

How to Filter the Data with keyword query ?
example like this:

All data : https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all

search with keyword : https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/nesia

Answer (score 0):

First decode your JSON string:

```
$countries = json_decode($json);
```

Then you can filter the resulting array using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$property = 'name';
$keyword = 'nesia';

$result = array_filter($countries, function($country) use ($property, $keyword) {
    return strpos($country->$property, $keyword) !== false;
});
```

Using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in the callback will check for the keyword in the name of each item. Be sure to use strict comparison (`!==` rather than `!=`) so matches at the beginning of the name (index 0) will not be excluded.

Comment: I get blank array []

Comment: If you're using the example array shown in your question with this exact code, then that's just because none of the names in that array contain "nesia".

Answer (score 0):

The following code will filter that JSON data by name:

```
$term = 'nesia';

$data = json_decode($json);
$filtered = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($term) {
   return stripos($item->name, $term) !== false;
});

print_r($filtered);
```

Comment: You must `use ($term)` in the callback, or it will be undefined in that scope.

Answer (score -2):

You have to read that url into a string. Then, you should use the json_decode() Php function (if that's what you mean by keyword).

You can read that url with a curl command :

```
$fp = fopen("curl_error.txt", "w");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://osteohickson.com/a/misc/rest_copy/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result));

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

However, that url: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all" is forbidden when I try it. That means you need a username and password to acccess it's data. Since I don't have it, I made a copy of that string on another server for testing purposes.

Now that you can "get" the data, you want to check what to do with it.